# PHP don't create the folder mkdir()

Tags: php, apache

I trying create new folder using PHP localhost/PhpProject3/create.php:

```
<?php mkdir('newdir', 0777); ?>
```

but this code doesn't do it. It also doesn't work :

```
<?php mkdir('/var/www/PhpProject3/newdir',0777); ?>
```

I installed LAMP. I think the problem is in the settings (maybe chmod ?) because PHP script works. For example i create simple test.php:

```
<?php echo 'Great'; ?>
```

and run it: `localhost/PhpProject3/test.php` the result is Great.

I use Netbeans.
Here are files: /var/www/PhpProject3 .
I run it: localhost/PhpProject3/...
The content of /etc/apache2/sites-available/default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I also can't create file using touch().

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Most likely you're not allowed to write there, web servers aren't generally allowed to write to the directories or files it serves (for good reason). If you need a writable directory, you'll need to explicitly do a chmod to allow the web server to write there. Just don't do it on the server root, but as specific a subdirectory as you can.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Which user does your webserver run as? You can see that if you write

```
ps aux
```

and take a look. It is probably the user www-data (if you use ubuntu).

Then you chown the dir to that user and give the user write permissions to the directory.

> chown www-data /var/www/PhpProject3

and

> chmod u+w /var/www/PhpProject3

An alternative is to instead use group permissions.

> chgrp www-data /var/www/PhpProject3

and

> chmod g+w /var/www/PhpProject3

assuming the webserver runs as group www-data.

Comment: It works but I can't create new php file in Netbeans. How can I change chmod to create, delete and edit files without root permision ?

Comment: Not possible if you are not root, you can make the directory all writable if you dare, its chmod a+w thedir

Comment: I can't for example copy file to folder "dir". I add user to www-data group and chmod: drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 maj  4 19:13 dir . How can I edit files in dir folder (without root permision) ?

Comment: If the files are already existing, you cannot modify them if the file permission themselves does not allow it, even if they are in a writable directory. The only thing directory writability gives you is ability to add/remove files to the dir.

Comment: Now when this question has got somewhat old, I have to tell that I never let the webserver store files in the file system, but instead I use the database. The performance is about equal, but gives you the freedom to not open up the file system. The column type is either mediumblob (16M) or longblob (4G).

Answer (score 3):

Hard to guess whats really the problem, I assume permissons or path problems. You should check the return value of `mkdir()`:

```
if(!mkdir()) {
    print_r(error_get_last());
}
```

Further you should learn enable error messages. `mkdir()` would trigger one if it fails. They are disabled by default as it could be a security risk in a production system. But when you are developing you **MUST** enable them. You can enable it in the `php.ini` of development system:

*php.ini*:

```
...
display_errors=1
...
log_errors=1
...
error_log="/path/to/writable/file"
...
error_reporting=E_ALL
```

After modifying the `php.ini` don't forget to restart the web server.

Answer (score -2):

there is a private temp location in centos 7 that is very annoying sometimes with php especially the mkdir command

To disable this behavior, you can set PrivateTmp=false in /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service

then systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl restart httpd

HTH.